# How does the default locale "root" work in ICU?

Tags: c++, c, linux, icu

Currently seeing discrepancies in how default locale "root" behaves in Linux and Windows.

Using ICU v54.1

In Windows, we are seeing the `Locale::getDefault()` as en_GB. 
Platform: WIndows Server 2012 R2

In Linux, we are seeing the `Locale::getDefault()` as "root". 
Platform: CentOS 7
`strace -e file /usr/bin/locale` gives

```
execve("/usr/bin/locale", ["locale"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB"
LC_TIME="en_GB"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB"
LC_PAPER="en_GB"
LC_NAME="en_GB"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB"
LC_ALL=en_GB
```

At the moment not sure how "root" locale is mapped! After googling, seen it is could be mapped to en_US_POSIX - how can this be verified?

When printing out list of `NumberFormat::getAvailableLocales`, only getting short names instead of the full names when using `locale.getDisplayName(name)`

Although it works as expected, when specifying `Locale::setDefault(locid)`,
which is not ideal!

Also tried with `export LC_ALL=C`, but this did not have affect on default locale in ICU.

Ideally in the code just setting the locale as "C" would be sufficient and not manage the default.

```
icu::Locale::Locale("C");
```

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use `getDisplayName(Locale, UnicodeString name)` to return display name specific to locale when the default is 'root'

For example;

```
    const icu::Locale fallbackDisplayNameLocale = icu::Locale("en_US");
    UnicodeString name(icu_locale.getName());
    std::string displayName;
    if (strcmp(icu::Locale::getDefault().getLanguage(), "root") == 0)
    {
        icu_locale.getDisplayName(fallbackDisplayNameLocale, name).toUTF8String(displayName);
    } else {
        icu_locale.getDisplayName(name).toUTF8String(displayName);
    }
```

Possibly this helps someone